# access token validation in new curity version

Tags: access-token, identity, curity

I see that curity has changed the format of the access token in recent product releases. It has some extra characters now.
I have a question, if the access token issue to a client from older version had longer validity,
will that older access token be introspected successfully in new version ?

Thanks
Charan

we have upgraded the curity version from 6 to 8 and had doubts about the format of access token

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the introspection will continue to work as before.